question about pir sensor lhi878
I am conducting an experiment with the Lhi 878 sensor, and when I input 5V, the output is connected to an oscilloscope without any significant load. The output is detected around 1V within a range of approximately 0.10V. Is this normal behavior, or is there an issue? If there is an issue, what could be the problem?
